# Why Azure SignalR function returns CORS error on localhost testing

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I am trying to learn how to use `Azure function` and `SignalR` to create a server-less design. for this I have created a following class for `Azure function` :

```
    public static class NotifactionR
    {

        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "my-hub")]
            SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {
            // connectionInfo contains an access key token with a name identifier claim set to the authenticated user
            return connectionInfo;
        }

        [FunctionName("NotifactionR")]
        public static Task NotifactionR([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
            [SignalR(HubName = "my-hub")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());

            return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    // the message will only be sent to these user IDs
                    UserId = "userId1",
                    Target = "OnNewEvent",
                    Arguments = new[] { eventGridEvent.Data }
                });
        }
    }
```

I have used the following configuration on my `local.settings.json`to enable local testing:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://myservice.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=myaccess-token;Version=1.0;",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:7071",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
}
```

and to test this, just created an `HTML file` which contains a following script:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7071/api", { headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:7071'}})
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
      .build();

connection.on('OnNewEvent', ProcessMyEvent);
connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));
console.log('connecting...');

connection.start()
    .then(() => data.ready = true)
    .catch(console.error);
```

I am seeing the following error when I open the HTML file on my Chrome (issue is almost same in firefox as well):

```
connecting...
Utils.ts:189 [2019-07-27T16:13:01.573Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
Utils.ts:189 [2019-07-27T16:13:01.573Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'.
Utils.ts:189 [2019-07-27T16:13:01.575Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate.

SignalRTest.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7071/api/negotiate' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Utils.ts:182 [2019-07-27T16:13:02.147Z] Warning: Error from HTTP request. 0: .
Utils.ts:179 [2019-07-27T16:13:02.148Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error
Utils.ts:179 [2019-07-27T16:13:02.148Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error
Error
    at new HttpError (Errors.ts:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (XhrHttpClient.ts:76)
```

does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

**Update 1**

Here is my `test.html` file I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@aspnet/signalr@1.1.4/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:7071';

        function initialize() {
            const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(window.apiBaseUrl + "/api", { headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:7071' } })
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
                .build();

            connection.on('OnNewEvent', ProcessMyEvent);
            connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));
            console.log('connecting...');

            connection.start({ withCredentials: false })
                .then(() => console.log('ready...'))
                .catch(console.error);

        }
        function ProcessMyEvent(vehicle) {
            alert("ProcessMyEvent CALLED");
        }

        initialize();


    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

**Update 2:**

I have also tried to run this from a command prompt with the following command:

`c:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.26.0\cli\func host start --cors * --pause-on-error`

still I get the same error

Comment: Your CORS config in local.settings.json is incorrect. The entry you currently have is `http://localhost:7071` and that's the function host. You need the web page's origin in that entry.

Comment: There's no need to add the headers in the JavaScript client. You also should consider not using a dash `-` in the hub name. It might work but there's a chance that it might not.

Comment: Also... how are you opening test.html?

Comment: @AnthonyChu: Thanks, I have also tested with `CORS:"*"`  but see the same errors. Also `.withUrl(window.apiBaseUrl + "/api")`does not help. Any idea what else I may be missing?

Comment: Also I am opening the file in my browser directly as `file:///d:/myTestfile.html`

Comment: Is your app on GitHub? You cannot use * because credentials support is on, it must be the origin of your **web page**. Also, what browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Hi ! I've got the exact same problem for 3 days but from an Angular app, have you any solution ?

Comment: @ChristopheGigax: Actually issue was that I was just opening a html file directly and this was causing this issue, once I hosted this page, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a red herring and doesn't appear to be CORS related to me. I see you're using the Azure SignalR Service, the way you connect to this is different to standard SignalR.

**The `negotiate` function behaves differently with the SignalR Service.** `negotiate` will return some data along with with accessToken and the URL of your SignalR Service, you'll need to use this URL instead to connect.

I've added an example below of how it should work. (I haven't tested this, but hopefully you get the idea).

```js
function initialize() {
    axios.get(window.apiBaseUrl+"/api/negotiate").then(response => {        
        const options = {
            accessTokenFactory: () => response.data.accessToken
        }
        const socket = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(response.data.url, options)
            .build(SignalR.HttpTransportType.None)

        connection.on('OnNewEvent', ProcessMyEvent);
        connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));
        console.log('connecting...');

        connection.start({ withCredentials: false })
            .then(() => console.log('ready...'))
            .catch(console.error);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for us when we want to use a linux function app, also in case if you wish to use * as allowed origins in the cors configuration on the Azure portal under the Configuration for the function app. Thank you so much.